Pseudo-spectra of a dynamical system
This question is about the pseudo spectra of a dynamic system. What does a following system of two second order equations say in terms of pseudo-spectral analysis? Here is a system where $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are functions of time:
$$\begin{cases}\partial^2 x/\partial t^2-2 a \partial y/\partial t+b^2 x &=& 2qa^2x\\ \partial^2 y/\partial t^2 + 2a \partial x/\partial t+b^2 y &=& 0\end{cases} $$
where $b > a > 0$ and $q$ are constants. $q$ is a small parameter that can introduce instability in the system.
P.S. This is math & physics related question, and I am asking a pseudo-spectra insight to understand how pseudo-spectra 'picture' is related to waves I saw long time ago that are, for example, responsible for producing a linear instability in the dynamical systems. Here is a link to a specific note that analysis above system the way I used in my research related to space, solar and lab plasma phenomena:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333811790_The_Physics_of_Instability_Inhomogeneity_Generated_Waves

Please rewrite your equations using MathJax.

@Gonçalo Done (I imagine that the asker hasn't any knowledge of Mathjax)

A nicely written document here using Fourier methods.

I believe that the pseudo-spectrum OP is referring to is in the sense of this, not the numerical discretization technique. That being said, you can transform any 2nd order system into a first order system by introducing new variables $u = x'$, $v = y'$
